# Problem with admins and non-admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

im using extJS 3.0.0, rails 2.3.11, ruby 1.8.

tables: `users -> id, name, is_admin`

```
question -> id, user_id, text
```

I want to do: If is_admin = 1 - he may see ALL questions. If is_admin = 0 and user_id = 7, he (user number 7) may see only HIS questions (he added 2 for example). How i can do it? In controller i do following trip, but nothing...

my_controller

```
@questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", session[:user].id])
```

in my view (with extJS)

```
<% if !@questions %>
shows...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check condition for is_admin or not:-
In Controller

```
if session[:user].is_admin == 1
  @questions = Question.find(:all)
else
  @questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", session[:user].id])
end
```

and in views have a loop to display all the questions.

Thanks.....